# Can not brew install gcc48 on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

Who have already successfully used homebrew to install the latest GCC 4.8.1 on Mac OS X(10.8.4)? I am always stuck when it runs to "make bootstrap".

```
$brew install gcc48
==> Downloading ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc48-4.8.1.tar.bz2
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
==> make bootstrap
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I've just done precisely this install. Be patient – that step does take a long time and is very CPU intensive. On my (admittedly old) Macbook Pro it took over 30 minutes to complete. I suggest you try running it again and just leaving it until it's done.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9-20131229: 1020 files, 145M, built in 22.1 minutes

Comment: On a 2010 13" MBA: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2: 1028 files, 142M, built in 78.4 minutes

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.1: 1152 files, 203M, built in 26.5 minutes

Comment: Does *brew* build everything from source?

Comment: today /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1353 files, 248M, built in 93.9 minutes

Comment: Cheers to that:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3: 1138 files, 165M, built in 74.4 minutes on a 2012 MBP

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1353 files, 248M, built in 133.0 minutes

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1285 files, 215M, built in 37.6 minutes on Macbook Pro Retina A1502.

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0: 1,390 files, 254.9M, built in 81 minutes 11 seconds Even though I have 16 GB RAM and SSD T.T

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0: 1,390 files, 254.9M, built in 77 minutes 49 seconds.
2.7 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 GB, HDD

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0: 1,361 files, 261.7M, built in 110 minutes 28 seconds 3.2GHz Intel Core i7, 16GB.

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0: 1,435 files, 282.4M, built in 55 minutes 53 seconds  -- Late 2013 MBP Retina

Comment:   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0: 1,445 files, 288.9M, built in 105 minutes 49 seconds  -- MBP 15 - Mid 2010 i5 2.4GHz (with multi lib)

Comment:  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0: 1353 files, 241M, built in 57.9 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it but the process has been slow, about 70 minutes:

/ usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2: 1028 files, 142M, built in 73.8 minutes

Is this normal?

Comment: I've been waiting five hours at the "make bootstrap" step.

Comment: I've been waiting for 20 days to complete the build.

Comment: i started a year ago and am still waiting :D

Comment: it took me 104 minutes to install GCC on MacBook Air 2013:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc6/6.2.0: 1,435 files, 275.2M, built in 104 minutes 9 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Just to give more evidence of the long build time,

/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2: 1028 files, 142M, built in 36.6 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I found this page searching google, and while I know compiling can take a long time, gcc48 on a Core2Duo 2010 Macbook Air really drags it out:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2: 1028 files, 142M, built in 79.5 minutes

just hang in there!